# jQuery draggable creates duplicate sub items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery UI draggable function. The full code is more complicated so I just created a simple test scenario to troubleshoot the bug here: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TpUx5/)**

There are two sections "top" and "content". There is a yellow button in the "top" section which is draggable.

When I drag the yellow button at the top and drop it to the gray "content" area, it will show this in the gray content:

Yellow Box 1
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Add New Item (button)

When I click on the "Add New Item" button, "Item 4" text will be added under Item 3 text.
When I click on the "Add New Item" button again, "Item 5" text will be added under Item 4 text and so on...

It is work as expected. However, the problem arises when I do another dragging of the yellow button at the top and drop it in the gray area, which I will have something like this:

Yellow Box 1
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
Add New Item

Yellow Box 2
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Add New Item

So when I go back and every time I click on the Add New Item button under Yellow Box 1, it adds TWO new items for every click instead of just one (it will add Item 6 and Item 7 under Item 5) which is not what I wanted.

I tried to cancel event bubbling and some other things but somehow it didn't work. When I isolated the same scenario without using the jQuery UI draggable function, then it behaves as expect. So I guess the bug is related to how I implemented the draggable function. Thank you for your help.

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#content').sortable({
        placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight'
    });

    $(".top-icon").draggable({
        connectToSortable: '#content',
        helper: myHelper,
        stop: handleDragStop
    });

    function myHelper(event) {
        return $(this).clone();
    }

    var i = 1;
    function handleDragStop(event, ui) {
        var current_text = '<div class="color-box"><b>Yellow Box ' + i + '</b>'
            + '<div class="yellow-content">'
            + '<div class="item">Item 1</div>'
            + '<div class="item">Item 2</div>'
            + '<div class="item">Item 3</div>'
            + '<div class="add-item">Add New Item</div>'
            + '</div>'
            + '</div>';
        $('#content .top-icon').after(current_text);

        i++;

        var $new_insert_item =  $('#content .top-icon').next();
        $('#content .top-icon').remove();  // remove the clone .top-icon inside #content

        console.log('hi');
        // when click on Add New Item button
        $('.color-box').on('click', '.add-item', function() {

            var $this = $(this);
            var item_count = $this.siblings('.item').length + 1;
            console.log (item_count);

            var str_item = '';
            str_item = '<div class="item">Item ' + item_count + '</div>';

            $(str_item).insertBefore($this);
        });
    }
    // end of handleDragStop
});
```

Comment: Can you put this in jsfiddle? It would make it easier to fix the problem.

Comment: It's already included in the first paragraph: http://jsfiddle.net/TpUx5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is that, binding the click event inside the `handleDragStop` binds events to the existing already dragged item as well so the existing dragged items gets the click event added up by 1 during each drag. So instead bind the event outside and have the event bound to `#content` (if this is the container that exist in DOM even before the first drag) to be delegated.

```
  $('#content').on('click', '.add-item', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var item_count = $this.siblings('.item').length + 1;
        console.log(item_count);
        var str_item = '';
        str_item = '<div class="item">Item ' + item_count + '</div>';
        $(str_item).insertBefore($this);
    });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uNpFG/)**

Comment: Hi PSL. I have another question related to this and wonder if you can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463617/apply-double-click-on-draggable-items . Thank you.