# Apply double click on draggable items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a yellow button that can be dragged and dropped on the gray panel. I use "handleDragStop" function to handle all the tasks that need to be done when users drag and drop the yellow button. Everything works great. However, I wonder how do I enable the behavior where users double click on the yellow button and have the same behavior as when they drag and drop?

```
$(".top-icon").draggable({
        connectToSortable: '#content',
        helper: myHelper,
        stop: handleDragStop
});

function handleDragStop(event, ui) {
        var current_text = '<div class="color-box"><b>Yellow Box ' + i + '</b>' + '<div class="yellow-content">' + '<div class="item">Item 1</div>' + '<div class="item">Item 2</div>' + '<div class="item">Item 3</div>' + '<div class="add-item">Add New Item</div>' + '</div>' + '</div>';
        $('#content .top-icon').after(current_text);

        i++;

        var $new_insert_item = $('#content .top-icon').next();
        $('#content .top-icon').remove(); // remove the clone .top-icon inside #content

        console.log('hi');
        // when click on Add New Item button
}
// end of handleDragStop
```

I can apply dblclick event after calling draggable like this:

```
$(".top-icon").draggable({
        connectToSortable: '#content',
        helper: myHelper,
        stop: handleDragStop
})
.dblclick(function() {

    alert('hi');
    // Do the same tasks as handleDragStop....

});
```

However, I wonder if there is a way I can share the functionality of handleDragStop for both draggable and dblclick so that I don't need to maintain a function handleDragStop for draggable and another similar function as handleDragStop for dblcclick? Thank you for your help.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uNpFG/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handleDragStop() function should work fine in both event handlers. The only draggable-specific code in it was `$('#content .top-icon').after(current_text);` and CMIIW but I don't see why you couldn't do `$('#content').append(current_text);` just as well, which would work in both cases.  Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/Tt7Fb/

JS:

```
$(function () {

    $('#content').sortable({
        placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight'
    });


    $(".top-icon").draggable({
        connectToSortable: '#content',
        helper: myHelper,
        stop: handleDragStop
    }).dblclick(function(e) {

    handleDragStop(e);

});;


    function myHelper(event) {
        return $(this).clone();
    }

    var i = 1;

    function handleDragStop(event, ui) {
        debugger;

        var current_text = '<div class="color-box"><b>Yellow Box ' + i + '</b>' + '<div class="yellow-content">' + '<div class="item">Item 1</div>' + '<div class="item">Item 2</div>' + '<div class="item">Item 3</div>' + '<div class="add-item">Add New Item</div>' + '</div>' + '</div>';
        $('#content').append(current_text);

        i++;

        var $new_insert_item = $('#content .top-icon').next();
        $('#content .top-icon').remove(); // remove the clone .top-icon inside #content

        console.log('hi');
        // when click on Add New Item button



    }
    // end of handleDragStop


    $('#content').on('click', '.add-item', function () {

        var $this = $(this);
        var item_count = $this.siblings('.item').length + 1;
        console.log(item_count);

        var str_item = '';
        str_item = '<div class="item">Item ' + item_count + '</div>';

        $(str_item).insertBefore($this);


    });
});
```

Comment: The reason $('#content .top-icon').after(current_text); should be used when users drag and drop because they may want to drop the newest elements in the position that is not the last child of #content. If users use double click then $('#content').append(current_text); can be used. I just need to set up the condition whether users use drag and drop or double click and use the right way of adding the new element. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.